# How to copy specific columns in specific order from one sheet to another?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to copy date and time, code and names from a big data sheet, which contains multiple columns. Row counts may differ.

The sequence of actions should be:

1. Copy the consecutive Range from **A3**  which is the first active cell through to the data at column AZ - This is a manual selection.
2. Using the VBA linked Command button start the process of copying data in next sheet:
   for example

> ```
> sheet1.column B  = sheet2.column A
> sheet2.column B= "" 
> 'empty and data copy is not needed, please just generate the empty row
> sheet1.column Y = sheet2.column C
> ```

3. After the copying process is over, clear all data from sheet1

My core problem is the data count for above rows differs every time. I can't find a correct sequence of commands to get these columns in the order I need from sheet1. To add to that, the formatting breaks and the time values are 'stringified', so it can't be reused.

The generated data needs to be exported to another workbook and the copying process is critically important as I do it repeatedly. Locating and copying each column manually every time.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to your problem is of the form **f(x) = y** where **x** is the column no. of the source sheet and **y** is the column number of that very same column on the destination sheet. 
f(x) is a simple mapping between a Source column and transformed into a destination column no.

As you still need to define the problem better by including sample data, I'll simply brief you on The 3 steps to resolve your problem. 
I hope you know your VBA well enough to encode the steps into the specific VBA code you need to solve this permanently.

1. Create a sheet as a "ControlPanel" that maps the columns you need.
   [image]
2. Assuming your sheets are named appropriately as per the code below.
3. Kindly do apply your VBA skills and discretion to customize the code below as per your needs.

   ```
   Public Sub Add_Msng_And_Check_Prev_EmpData()
   ''  Objective : Check missing employees from the incoming data placed in the Destination_Sheet sheet which is the client's format.
   ''  The _Source_Sheet sheet is our destination where processed data sits,
   ''  columns from Destination_Sheet are mapped to specific columns of the _Source_Sheet sheet.
   ''  Copy the missing emp codes to these mapped columns.

   '' Support :  myfullnamewithoutspaces@gmail.com
   '' Status : Production 14-Dec-2016 10.32 PM
   '' Version : 1.0
   '' To Do : 10 is the column number on Source_Sheet where the emp code resides
   '' Convert this magic number to a generic solution

   Dim Src_Sheet, Destination_Sheet As Worksheet
   Dim Dest_Sheet_Column_Mapping, Src_Sheet_Column_Location As Range

   Set Src_Sheet = Sheets("Source_Sheet")
   Set Destination_Sheet = Sheets("Destination_Sheet")

   Set Dest_Sheet_Column_Mapping = Sheets("ControlPanel").Range("A2:A60")
   Set Src_Sheet_Column_Location = Sheets("ControlPanel").Range("D2:D60")

   Dim myMap()  As Integer
   Dim myRow As Variant
   ReDim myMap(Dest_Sheet_Column_Mapping.Count + 1)

   '' Map the source_columns to the destination_columns
   For Each myRow In Src_Sheet_Column_Location
   '' Index corresponds to Source_Sheet column
   '' Value at Index to Destination_Sheet
   '' for eg: Destination_Sheet.column = myMap(Src_Sheet.column)
       myMap(myRow) = Dest_Sheet_Column_Mapping.Cells(myRow, 1).Value
   Next myRow

   Dim Primary_Key_Not_Null As Collection
   Set Primary_Key_Not_Null = New Collection
   Dim Master, Src_Sheet_Range, Src_Range As Range
   Dim MissingEmployeeCode, LookupValue, tempVar, LookupResult  As Variant
   Dim LastRow, i, Src_Range_Rows_Count, Src_Sheet_Range_Rows_Count As Integer

   '' This is the source of all new entries we need to search for.
   Set Src_Sheet_Range = Destination_Sheet.Range(Destination_Sheet.Cells(1, myMap(10)), Destination_Sheet.Cells(Destination_Sheet.Cells(1048576, myMap(10)).End(xlUp).Row, myMap(10)))
   Src_Sheet_Range_Rows_Count = Src_Sheet_Range.Rows.Count

   '' This is the database of all previous existing entries we need to search against.
   Set Src_Range = Src_Sheet.Range(Src_Sheet.Cells(1, 10), Src_Sheet.Cells(Src_Sheet.Cells(1048576, 10).End(xlUp).Row, 10))
   Src_Range_Rows_Count = Src_Range.Rows.Count

       For i = 3 To Src_Sheet_Range_Rows_Count
       '' Skip the blank rows and header at rows 0 to 2
           On Error Resume Next
           LookupValue = Destination_Sheet.Cells(i, myMap(10)).Value
               LookupResult = Application.Match(LookupValue, Src_Range, 0)
                   If (IsError(LookupResult)) Then
                   '' To Do : Check for Duplicates within the previously added values
                   '' LookupValue becomes your missing empcode and i is the row number it's located at
                   '' The row number i becomes critical when you want to copy the same record that you have just found missing.
                       Primary_Key_Not_Null.Add i '' LookupValue
                       '' LookupValue is the actual missing empcode, however we need the row number for the copy operation later
                   End If
       Next i

   LastRow = Src_Sheet.Cells(1048576, 10).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
   Dim FirstRow, LastColumn, j, Src_Range_Columns_Count As Integer
   FirstRow = LastRow

   ''--Phase 3--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   '' Objective : Get and paste data for each missing empcode
   With Src_Range
       LastColumn = .Cells(1, 1).End(xlToRight).Column
       LastRow = Primary_Key_Not_Null.Count + FirstRow
       Set Src_Range = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(LastRow, LastColumn))
       Src_Range_Columns_Count = Src_Range.Columns.Count
           For i = FirstRow To LastRow ''FirstRow + 3 '' Commented for Debugging
               For j = 1 To Src_Range_Columns_Count '' 59
               ''  The simple logic is Row Numbers and Column numbers obtained from all the above operations
               ''  define the cells in the Src_Sheet sheet that we need this data pasted ito.
               ''  For details please see the code below.
               Src_Sheet.Cells(i, j).Value = Destination_Sheet.Cells(Primary_Key_Not_Null(i - FirstRow + 1), myMap(j)).Value
               Next j
           Next i
   End With

   ''--Phase 4--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ''  Objective : For the previous range in Source_Sheet, check each cell in each column against the mapped columns in the Destination_Sheet.
   ''  When you find a discrepancy: style it Bad, for the matches: style it Good,
   ''  for the not found : Style it neutral.
   LastRow = FirstRow
   FirstRow = 2
   Set Src_Range = Src_Sheet.Range(Src_Sheet.Cells(2, 1), Src_Sheet.Cells(LastRow, LastColumn))
   Src_Range.Style = "Normal"

   Dim FoundRow, FoundColumn As Integer
   FoundRow = 0
   FoundColumn = 10
   Dim LookupRange, LookupDatabase As Range
   Set LookupRange = Src_Sheet.Range(Src_Sheet.Cells(1, 10), Src_Sheet.Cells(LastRow, 10))
   Set LookupDatabase = Destination_Sheet.Range(Destination_Sheet.Cells(1, myMap(10)), Destination_Sheet.Cells(Src_Sheet_Range_Rows_Count, myMap(10)))

   Dim FoundRows As Collection
   Set FoundRows = New Collection

   '' Locate the row of each employee code on Emp Master, push it into a collection and let the emp code be it's key
   Dim LookupRange_Row_Count As Integer
   LookupRange_Row_Count = LookupRange.Rows.Count
   For i = 2 To LookupRange_Row_Count
   On Error Resume Next
       FoundRow = Application.Match(LookupRange.Cells(i, 1).Value, LookupDatabase, 0)
       If (Not IsError(FoundRow)) Then
       '' myRow contains EmpCode which is the key, FoundRow = Where I Found it, becomes the value.
        FoundRows.Add FoundRow, CStr(LookupRange.Cells(i, 1).Value)
       End If
   Next i

   Dim Src_Sheet_Value, EmpMstrValue, myEmpCodeString As String

   For i = FirstRow To LastRow '' 2 to 1029
       For j = 1 To Src_Range_Columns_Count '' 59
       ''  Handle 4 cases.
       ''  1.  Src_Sheet Cell Value Found and matches = Good
       ''  2.  Src_Sheet Cell Value Found and does not match = Bad
       ''  3.  Src_Sheet Cell Value Not Found or not in Scope and hence does not match = Neutral
       ''  4.  Src_Sheet Cell Value is a duplicate of a value which is already checked earlier. = ??
       Src_Sheet_Value = Src_Sheet.Cells(i, j).Value
           myEmpCodeString = CStr(LookupRange.Cells(i, 1).Value)
           myRow = CInt(FoundRows(myEmpCodeString))
       EmpMstrValue = Destination_Sheet.Cells(myRow, myMap(j)).Value

       ''  Implements 1.  Src_Sheet Cell Value Found and matches = Good

       If Src_Sheet_Value = EmpMstrValue Then
           Src_Sheet.Cells(i, j).Style = "Good"
       Else
           Src_Sheet.Cells(i, j).Style = "Bad"
       End If

       Next j
   Next i
   End Sub
   ```

I found myself in the same situation as yourself sometime back. Although the code is conceptually simple, it requires you to thoroughly define your problem in the Source, Destination, Transformation pattern.
Do Feel free to mail me at myfullnamewithoutspaces@gmail.com. I'll assist any way I can.